# Framework7->CSS: How to make tabs under popover scrollable

Tags: css

My question pertains to [framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/#.Vp_fByp96hc) implementation, but is basically a CSS question:

I have `tabs` under a `popover`. I need to make these tabs content vertically scrollable. The default implementation of  tabs has scrolling enables, but when these tabs are placed under popover (modal if you like) then these tabs stop being scrollable.

I have made a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbvqksu8/2/), to better explain the issue. In the fiddle, if you click "`Click Me`" and then go to "`Account`" tab you will notice that the tab is not scrollable.

THanks

Comment: Why in the world did you include the entire CSS on that JSFiddle :D

Comment: well I was hosting it in http, and jsfiddle wanted me a https link. So... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/xbvqksu8/3/

This CSS was added:

```
 .popover-inner {
    max-height:100vh !important;
  }
.list-block ul {
    overflow-Y:auto;
  }
```

If you want your menu to fit in the screen better change the `100vh` to something lower. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. Spent a long time trying to figure this.

Answer (score 0):

@Fausto NA is great.

There is a little problem because the popover has top margin (usual 8px).

Therefore something like that is needed:

```
.popover-inner {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 8px) !important;      // last fallback
    max-height: -webkit-fill-available !important; // fallback: supported by many webviews
    max-height: stretch !important;                // still not widely supported
}
```

References: [Can I use Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width)